# What does selecting a Most Valuable Player in a Warzone do?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

After finishing a Warzone match, you can vote which of the players of your team is a Most Valuable Player.

How do the votes work? And what is the reward for being voted a MVP?

Comment: I would also add: Can you always vote for anyone on your team? Can you vote for yourself? Can you ever vote for anyone on the opposing team?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each vote gives the player an extra warzone commendation.

Each vote also provides you with 50 extra valor points.

Votes are given by players to other players based on their performance (or whoever they feel like).

To address Mufasa's comment/question:

You can only vote for your own team.

You cannot vote for yourself.

Again, you can only vote for your own team.

Sometimes the UI bugs out at the moment and you won't see the little shield icon to vote, just hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> two times and it will reload your UI and let you vote.

Comment: And you can vote for _anyone_ on your team then too, yes?

Comment: You can only vote for other players that are not yourself.